# Problem when use zebrautility on flutter from pub.dev

Tags: flutter, syntax-error, zebra-printers

I recently add **zebrautility: ^0.0.38** from  https://pub.dev/packages/zebrautility to my flutter project. When i follow the steps on documentation i have the following error:
[image]

I don't know why this happen, someone can help me?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, There is no sample code available, how to use this library in our project

Comment: This is the way i fixed https://github.com/MythiCode/zebra_utlity/issues/7. But finally I decide use another library because this is not than flexible like I want, is very painfull get the state of result on a impresion, this library work to me better pub.dev/packages/zsdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that the parameters of the method. This is the way:

```
ZebraPrinter zebraPrinter = await Zebrautility.getPrinterInstance(
onPrinterFound: onPrinterFound('hoid-connect', '192.168.43.80', true),
onPrinterDiscoveryDone: onPrinterDiscoveryDone,
onChangePrinterStatus: onChangePrinterStatus,
onPermissionDenied: onPermissionDenied);

print(zebraPrinter);

zebraPrinter.connectToPrinter("192.168.43.80");
zebraPrinter.print(data);
}

Function onPrinterFound = (String name, String ipAddress, bool isWifi) {
print("PrinterFound :" + name + ipAddress);
};
```

Comment: If the onPrinterFound function changes, onChangePrinterStatus starts to give the same error. Also, It's not working for Bluetooth printers.